# Extract user address book from Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange-2013, mailbox

How can I extract user address book from Exchange 2013 mailbox? Is there a power shell command to extract it into csv or vcf?

Answer (score 0):

The Exchange address book is based on the underlying ActiveDirectory which you can query with an LDAP client (e.g. [apache directory studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/)). Via that way you should be able to create a popper *.CSV file with the infos needed. Simply connect the LDAP client towards an domain controller.

*The address book from Exchange is normally generated on an Exchange Server every x hours (based on Active Directory infos) and then the clients can download it as offline address book. (more infos [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/exchange/2013/01/14/managing-oab-in-exchange-server-2013/))*